# JAVA - Gerar uma palavra aleatoria & embaralhada

Tags: java, random

Pretendo gerar uma palavra aleatoria e embaralhada apartir de um vector.
De momento já está a gerar uma palavra aleatória mas não embaralhada. Criei um metodo chamado scramble onde as palavras serão embaralhadas mas não sei não estou a conseguir chamar no Main.

Codigo actual:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class findthewordgame {
    public static void arrayword () {

        String[] wordgame = new String[5];

        wordgame[0] = "TEA";
        wordgame[1]= "COFFE";
        wordgame[2]= "BOAT";
        wordgame[3]="SEA";
        wordgame[4]="SUN";


       int idx = new Random().nextInt(wordgame.length);
       String random = (wordgame[idx]);

       System.out.println(wordgame[idx]);

    }

    public static String scramble(Random random, String inputString )
    {
    // Convert your string into a simple char array:
    char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();

    // Scramble the letters using the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle, 
    for( int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++ )
    {
        int j = random.nextInt(a.length);
        // Swap letters
        char temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j];  a[j] = temp;
    }       

    return new String( a );
}

    public static void main (String[] args){
         arrayword();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer com que funciona basta chamar o método `scramble`, que não está a ser chamado. Poderia faze-lo com:

```
public static void arrayword () {

   ...
   System.out.println(scramble(new Random(), random));
}
```

E apesar de já funcionar não está muito bom pois está a ser criado outro objeto `Random` quando já tinha sido criado um anteriormente.

Podemos rever isso e outros detalhes do código e transforma-lo em:

```
//objeto que gera os aleatorios agora é sempre o mesmo e apenas criado uma vez
static Random aleatorio = new Random();

public static void arrayWord () { //agora o nome em camel case

    String[] wordgame = { //inicialização do array mais simples assim
        "TEA",
        "COFFEE",
        "BOAT",
        "SEA",
        "SUN"
    };

    int idx = aleatorio.nextInt(wordgame.length);
    String palavraEscolhida = (wordgame[idx]);

    System.out.println(palavraEscolhida); //escrever a variavel anterior, a escolhida
    System.out.println(scramble(palavraEscolhida));
}

//agora não recebe o aleatorio, usa o mesmo da classe
public static String scramble(String inputString ) 
{
    // Convert your string into a simple char array:
    char[] a = inputString.toCharArray();

    // Scramble the letters using the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle, 
    for( int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++ )
    {
        int j = aleatorio.nextInt(a.length);

        //Mais legível assim linha a linha
        char temp = a[i]; 
        a[i] = a[j];  
        a[j] = temp;
    }       

    return new String(a);
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/E4VdMj)

Comment: `String[] wordgame = {"TEA", "COFFE", "BOAT", "SEA", "SUN"};` - Mais simples ainda.

Comment: E já aproveitaria e arrumaria detalhes de estilo de código, tais como espaços a mais ou a menos, nomes de variáveis e usar `char[] a` ao invés de `char a[]`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim concordo e agradeço os comentários. Esse ultimo do `char a[]` nem tinha reparado!

Comment: fiz como sugerido está funcionando e não está. aparece a palavra duas vezes uma vez correctamente escrita e na mesma linha de novo mas embaralhada. eu pretendo que a palavra gere apenas uma vez e somente embaralhada. tem como ajudar sff?

Comment: bastou comentar System.out.println(palavraEscolhida); e ja ta dando.

Comment: @DianaMadeira tenha em consideração que o algoritmo que está a utilizar para baralhar (que eu não troquei propositadamente) não lhe garante a 100% que a palavra batalhada fique diferente da original, embora seja muito provável. Se imaginar numa palavra com 3 letras que troca: 1-3, 2-2 e 3-1 fica igual ao original. Para isso não acontecer teria que utilizar outro algoritmo, ou utilizando o mesmo continuar a baralhar a mesma palavra até ficar diferente.